# How to change color of focus rectangle of items in QTreeView?

Tags: qt, qt4

Is it possible to easily change color of dotted focus rectangle for items (rows consisting of multiple QStandardItems) in QTreeView ?

In stylesheet **QTreeView::item:focus** does not work

and I can't reimplement **paint** function in custom **QItemDelegate** since it overrides my stylesheet settings.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QTreeView::item:selected` works for me:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QFileSystemModel model;
    model.setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
    QTreeView tree;
    tree.setModel(&model);

    tree.setAllColumnsShowFocus(true);

    tree.setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:selected { border-color:green; "
                       "border-style:outset; border-width:2px; color:black; }");

    tree.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: As I said, this solution does not work for me, since I'm using TreeView with multiple columns and all of them show focus (**allColumnsShowFocus**=true). With this option set to false it works, but I need to have coloured rectangle around whole row, not just a single Item.

Comment: @DušoBrejka Try `QTreeView::item:selected`, which does work. The only problem is that it draws the border around each individual item in the row, instead of drawing one border around all of them. Perhaps you can stylize the font or background instead of the border? Anyways, I don't think it is possible to make one single border around all the columns in a row. And if you look closely (at least in Windows) the dotted border is there even if you stylize the border using the method above.

Comment: Thanks, it does work under certan circumstances but it's not what I wanted becouse I can have multiple rows selected and currently focused other row at once. So I guess there's no quick&easy solution for me.